# Fixed Navigation bar- how to set "margins" on each side of the bar

Tags: css, navigation, fixed, margins

could you please advise, how can I place a fixed navigation bar - width:100% in the center of the web, with 40px gap on the left and right side (I mean something like margin left/right-I know it doesn't work with position fixed...)

thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

width: calc((100%) - 80px);

add "margin: auto;" or anything that will center your nav so it will have 40px gapon both sides